# Driver unable to find element after click on angular link however the result shows in browser as well

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm getting stuck in Python Selenium with `angular` site **scraping** it's showing exception `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` when I click on its any link, chrome driver shows the result came into driver but when I try to find any element that came in the result `python selenium` showing exception.

```
driver.get("https://recruiting.adp.com/srccar/public/RTI.home?c=1153651&d=ExternalCareerSite&rb=ConstellisSite#/")
job_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='jobtitle job-title-link']")))
job = job_elements[0]
job.click()
//after some wait when elements visible into driver
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='jobTitle job-detail-title']").text
```

then exception shows so how can I extract elements that came after click in agular.
help will be appreciated.

Comment: your code works perfectly fine to me. No execptions

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. Just like the way you induced [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for *visibility_of_all_elements_located()* before collecting the desired elements, similarly to extract the text **K-9 Handler (Boston/Part Time)** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://recruiting.adp.com/srccar/public/RTI.home?c=1153651&d=ExternalCareerSite&rb=ConstellisSite#/')
  job_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='jobtitle job-title-link']")))
  job_elements[0].click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='jobTitle job-detail-title']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()` method:

  ```
  driver.get('https://recruiting.adp.com/srccar/public/RTI.home?c=1153651&d=ExternalCareerSite&rb=ConstellisSite#/')
  job_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='jobtitle job-title-link']")))
  job_elements[0].click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.jobTitle.job-detail-title"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  K-9 Handler (Boston/Part Time)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on *no such element* in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: this works only Python console but not working when run as spider. :(

Comment: @Rana.Amir What do you mean by `spider`? I don't see anything mentioned in your question regarding `spider`? Did you run the code with inmy answer? Can you let me know the status?

Comment: I meant when I ran this as a python scrapy spider  with command i.e `scrapy crawl spider_name` it not giving me any element after when I clicked on any link.